# Laravel belongsToMany only returning one record?

Tags: php, laravel

I have 3 tables, I'll try to describe the schema.

```
scraper_profiles
    id
    name

scraper_collections
    id
    name

scraper_collection_entries
    profile_id
    collection_id
```

I am trying to return the items that belong to a collection,

```
class ScraperCollection extends Model
{
    public function items()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(ScraperProfile::class, 'scraper_collection_entries', 'profile_id', 'collection_id');
    }
}
```

Although it only returns one record in my resource?

```
class CollectionResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'name' => $this->name,
            'creator' => new UserResource($this->creator),
            'items' => ScraperProfileResource::collection($this->items),
            'created_at' => $this->created_at,
            'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you receiving a collection or a single model only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Many to Many definition of foreign keys is reversed.

it should be:

```
 return $this->belongsToMany(
        ScraperProfile::class,
       'scraper_collection_entries',
       'collection_id',
       'profile_id');
```

A little thing to remember in Many to many relationship's definition:

*if the first parameter is class **A** then the last parameter of the definition should be the foreign key of **A** (`A_id`).*